# Split big query repeated column list of name/value fields into separate columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

With big query sql - what is the best way to make the entries of a repeated field columns? The table has a repeated field user_attributes which is a list of 30-ish records that each have two fields: `name` and `value`. there are almost always the same 30 names - for example suppose the names include `fieldA` and `fieldB`.

Without changing the number of rows, I want to add 30 columns with those names, and the data being the values. I’ve got this

```
   tbl2 AS (SELECT * EXCEPT(user_attributes, name, value), user_attribute.value AS fieldA
   FROM (tbl1 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tbl1.user_attributes) AS user_attribute) 
   WHERE user_attribute.name = 'fieldA'),
```

which unpacks one of the entries - but drops a few rows where it is missing (I’d rather have a null in those rows).
I could keep doing this, but would 30 such cross join unnest where filters be OK, or turn into an expensive query?

Or, is this not the best practice? I want to do group by on different user attribute fields - statistics, average, etc - so thats why I want to make the table more structured.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use CROSS JOIN UNNEST, instead you can unpack values in the select statement.
By this way, rows with NULL values won't be eliminated.

Example:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(user_attributes),
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(user_attributes) WHERE name = 'fieldA') as fieldA,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(user_attributes) WHERE name = 'fieldB') as fieldB,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(user_attributes) WHERE name = 'fieldC') as fieldC
FROM tbl1
```